# upload multiple images in database

Tags: asp.net

when i insert multiple images in database, my image name is not inserted in the database using stored procedure code is here

**upload.aspx.cs**

```
 Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            HttpFileCollection imgcoll = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < imgcoll.Count; i++)
            {
                imgcoll[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + imgcoll[i].FileName));
                col.Add(new img() { img_name = imgcoll[i].FileName });

                data.Add("@Id", null);
                data.Add("@Name", FileUpload1.FileName);
                con.ins("img", "insert", data);
            }`DataList1.DataSource = col;
            DataList1.DataBind();
```

**img.cs**

```
public string img_name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

connection class is

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crudConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

  public void ins(string pro, string insert_eve, Dictionary<string, string> table_col)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pro);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event", insert_eve);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", null);

        foreach (var pair in table_col)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

**upload.aspx**

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="upload_image">
    <div class="imaage_div">

        <img src='images/<%#Eval("img_name")%>' width="100px" height="100px"/>
        <div class="delete">            
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" style=" height: 20px; width: 20px" ImageUrl="~/images/Icon_delete.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("img_name") %>' OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command"/>
            </div>
    </div>                              
</div>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <br />

</div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="INsert" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```